# Setting the value of each element with minimum value in the row to 1 and others to 0 in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

This is what i am trying to do in MATLAB but can't seem to get around achieving it

**For each row in the filtered image, assign a value
of one to the pixels that have the minimum value
in that row and the other pixels to zero**

[image: casia]

Comment: `argmin()` immediately comes to mind: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24210-argmaxargmin/content/argmin.m

Comment: Matlab does have the built in min function but how would i traverse only individual rows and compute the min value of each and set it to one?

Comment: If you want help segmenting the pupil, I suggest asking on dsp.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/tY3YE.jpg');
img = rgb2gray(img); %# transform jpeg color image to grayscale

minValue = min(img,[],2);
%# set the pixels equal to the minimum value to 1
bw = bsxfun(@eq,img,minValue);
```

When I run this on the image you linked, I get

[image]

Which shows that there are plenty of border effects from median filtering. Removing the border 10 pixels, i.e. with

```
img = img(10:end-9,10:end-9);
```

and running the code again, I find

[image]

Which makes quite a bit more sense.

Comment: Perfect !! Although the output i get is different as you have stated but i got what i want thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve what you need through:

```
% Obtain the minimum in each row
mn = min(I,[],2);
% Set the pixels that are minimum to one, others to zero
eq = I == repmat(mn,1,size(I,2));
```

This code assumes that you have your image in `I`.

Comment: ??? Error using ==> eq
Number of array dimensions must match for binary array op.

Error in ==> Casedetect at 8
eq = I == repmat(mn,1,size(I,2));

Comment: It looks like the dimension of the image `I` that you use in `mn` is not the same as the one used in the `eq` variable. Also, try to `clear` those variables.

Comment: I just test for the rgb image, and the code also works with `repmat`, it create an `eq` logical image with 3 channels.